# Git: how to track who forced pushed remote code repository?

Tags: git

As we know, Git has a powerful option "-f" with "git push" command, which could change remote code repository history and committed change.

As a pure Git command line user, is there a way to track who just did that kind of thing to notify him/her not to do it again ? Maybe he/she is using some GUI tool and doesn't know what he/she is really doing.

BTW, commit history is ever the root that we can use to check what happened. but git-force-push just changed it so that (sounds like) all clues are lost.

Comment: If your central repo is on a server you maintain, you may be able to identify it by the web logs.

Comment: Thanks! It's on a server. but before making deep dive into web logs checking, is there more convenient way from Git itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git itself does not track that information. If you control the server, you could set up a [pre- or post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to record who pushed what and when.

For past occasions, if you use HTTPS or SSH protocols for pushing code, your web/ssh server logs might be of use in identifying past actors.

Comment: Thanks ! so there is no way to trace it from pure Git command lines ?

Comment: git runs everywhere.  it has no way of interfacing with every installation's identification practices.  When you set up a repo, you can, for instance, decide only to allow ssh or local users write access, and then you can record exactly who does what.  It's a common way to set up a repo, it's not hard, and git's explicitly built to support that.  Importing it so it works  "from pure Git" is just duplicating existing tools -- and their documentation -- and all their code -- and any current bugs -- but none of the people who actually know how to do that stuff.  Not widely considered a good move.